# Lumped parameter thermal network model of a motor (LPTN)

Tags: motor, temperature, thermal

I'm interested in designing a lumped parameter thermal network model for an electrical motor, in order to estimate the motor coil's temperature during transients. I know that a simple first order model might not be sufficient when the transients are long, so I was interested in using a higher order model. I came up with a network similar to:

[image]

Reading a bit more about the topic I noticed that there are 2 main forms of networks that are typically used:
The Cauer and Foster networks (with an existing mathematical conversion between the two).
[image]

As I mentioned the model that I was thinking about resembles the foster form where each capacitor is placed between the surrounding junction temperatures, as opposed to the Cauer form where all capacitors are grounded to the ambient temperature. I've read that the R-C parameters that are found (by curve fitting) from the foster model have no physical meaning, while the Cauer network parameters do have, and can be estimated from the geometrical and material properties.

I don't understand why this is the case. If for instance, inside the motor the permanent magnet is located between the frame and the airgap, shouldn't the corresponding capacitor in the network model be also placed between the frame and the airgap (like in the foster form) for the model to make sense? Why is Cauer network more physically correct?